# serversocket close after timeout

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I have a server code and I want the client thread in the server to close the server socket after given timeout.

the code in the client thread in the server:

```
serversocket.close();
```

but I want it to be closed after timeout not instantly when calling the close method.
and I want the client thread to continue its work for timeout time after that the socket should be closed, how could that be done?!

thanks in advance

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. If you don't want to close it now, close it later. Client-handling threads shouldn't be fiddling with the listening socket, and there is no API that will magically behave as you describe. Unclear what you're really trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 1):

Iam not sure if I get your point, but for timing you can use a Timer instance of `java.util.Timer` and use its schedule method to schedule your thread work

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
Thread.sleep(x);
```

x -> milliseconds

for example `Thread.sleep(1000);` it'll wait 1s then continues.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29

Comment: it should not wait I have mentioned that!